# Does the identity $ I(u) = c$ hold?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $(H, ||\cdot||)$ be a Hilbert space and let $I\in C^1 (H, \mathbb R)$.

Assume that $(u_n)_n\subset H$ is a bounded sequence in $H$ and let $u$ its weak limit.

Also, suppose that
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} I(u_n) = c>0$$
and
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} I'(u_n) = I'(u)$$
(in the sense of the dual space $H^*$ of $H$.

My question: is it possible to deduce that $$ I(u) = c?$$

I have the feeling that it is true, but I do not know how to prove it.
Anyone could please help with the proof or provide a counterexample?

Comment: Seems to be related to the Palais-Smale condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not true. Take $H=l^2$, $I(u) = (1-\|u\|^2)^2$, $u_n = e_n$. Then $I(e_n) = 0$, $I'(e_n) = 0$, $e_n \rightharpoonup 0$, but $I(0) =1\ne \lim I(e_n)$.